# PHP how to insert select box value into database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question
i already make a form to view two select box value with database and one text filed value
i want to know how to insert those value back into database with different table

my script on view select box value is something like this

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT gejala FROM gejala where idatribut =110000";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>
<select name="gejala1">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['gejala']."'>".$row['gejala']."</option>";
}
?>  
</select>


<p>Subatribut2
<?php
$query = "SELECT gejala FROM gejala where idatribut =110000";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>
<select name="gejala2">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['gejala']."'>".$row['gejala']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>          


<p>
    <label>value
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
      <input type="text" name="textfield">
    </label>  
<p>
<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit">    
<p>
```

how to know how to insert this value into another table(pucuk) with same field
thankyou

i already try insert script

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gejala1'])) {
    $gejala1 = $_POST['gejala1'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pucuk (gejala1) VALUES ({$gejala2})";
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('cbrteh', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['gejala2'])) {
    $gejala2 = $_POST['gejala2'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pucuk (gejala2) VALUES ({$gejala2})";
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('cbrteh', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}
}   
?>
  </form>
```

but when i hit submit button it still has no effect

Comment: your question not clear, but what ever i got from it is, you want a user select any option from drop down list and on submit form that selected value should insert into your desired table?

Comment: That's what I got as well m-t

Comment: @ m-t yes the table name is "pucuk"

Comment: Don't construct SQL statements from user-submitted input! - use a stored procedure. Just because the submitted value comes from a list that you generate doesn't mean it can't be hijacked for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

In while loop itself u can write insert query and send the option box value into the field u want,try it !

Comment: soory i forgot rest of the script actually there a submit button on this script i already do that but submit button has no response :)

Comment: If you forgot something then go back and edit your question to put it in! At the moment I see no "<form>" tag (although you have a closing tag) - that would certainly explain why your submit button doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

after a submit, your select option value will be in the $_POST[] variable under the name of your select. Namely, here "gejala2"

Answer (score 0):

put your code in a form with method=POST and after submitting your form you will get all your new values in _POST array 
for example

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$var1=$_POST['select1'];
$var2=$_POST['select2'];
$var3=$_POST['select3'];
//then write update/insert query as your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gejala1'])) {
    $gejala1 = $_POST['gejala1'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pucuk (gejala1) VALUES ({$gejala2})";
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('cbrteh', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['gejala2'])) {
    $gejala2 = $_POST['gejala2'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pucuk (gejala2) VALUES ({$gejala2})";
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('cbrteh', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}

?>
<form action="" method="POST"><!-- add this -->

<?php
$query = "SELECT gejala FROM gejala where idatribut =110000";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>
<select name="gejala1">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['gejala']."'>".$row['gejala']."</option>";
}
?>  
</select>


<p>Subatribut2
<?php
$query = "SELECT gejala FROM gejala where idatribut =110000";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>
<select name="gejala2">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['gejala']."'>".$row['gejala']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>          


<p>
    <label>value
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
      <input type="text" name="textfield">
    </label>  
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">    <!-- changed from type="button" to type="submit"> -->
<p>
</form>
```